# office deployment tool не скачивается

Tags: office

Попытался скачать office deployment tool, но получил следующее :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачивание после этого не начинается.
Office более недоступен или проблема в чем-то другом ?

Comment: У вас какие-то локальные проблемы, у меня только что скачалось без проблем

Comment: @andreymal  даже с другого устройства попробовал - всё тоже самое, безрезультатно.

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения, но вы не из России? Может быть моя проблема скачивания вызвана моим нынешним местоположением ?

Comment: Я из России, так что сам удивлён, что у меня всё скачалось

Answer (score 0):

Вот [сайт](https://winstall.app/apps/Microsoft.OfficeDeploymentTool), где можно скачать последнюю версию.

Comment: а что это за сайт?